# 2019 27-inch iMac with Retina 5K display

Tags: rendering

I am currently using a late 2014 27-inch iMac with Retina 5K with the following specs:

- 4 GHz Intel Core i7;
- 32 GB 1600 MHz DDR3 RAM;
- Radeon R9 M295X 4096 MB
- 3 GB fusion drive; AMD

Rendering my 3D scenes with the Cycles engine is sometimes taking a day or two which is tremendously slowing down my workflow.
I am thinking of upgrading to a new iMac with the following specs:

- 3.6GHz 8-core 9th-generation Intel Core i9 processor, Turbo Boost up to 5.0GHz;
- 64GB 2666MHz DDR4 memory RAM (from OWC, 3rd party;
- Radeon Pro Vega 48 with 8GB of HBM2 memory;
- 1TB SSD storage

Will rendering 3D scenes be more efficient and fast with such a new iMac?

Any feedback is appreciated

Sincerely,

Rio

Comment: Of course yes, that iMac is stronger than most of the gaming computer and your 2014 iMac. But, if the scene rendering over a day, that's not the hardware problem. You might want to check how to speed up your rendering by some tricks. Cause you will probably render the scene by a half day after you buy the new iMac

Comment: Or if you are sure that this project scale is too large. Then buying a new computer is kind of meaningless. Animation studio don't render those scene on single computer, or GPU. They render those thing in hundred of processor in parallel. You might want to check "**render farm**" for these kind of services.